# mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, linux-mint

I recently did installation of mint Linux.I have installed Apache2. Now i am tried to install PHP then i got an error like

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried the following code

```
  sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt
```

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmcrypt4 php-common php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json
  php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
Suggested packages:
  libmcrypt-dev mcrypt php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmcrypt4 php-common php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json
  php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,600 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libmcrypt4 amd64 2.5.8-3.3 [63.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php-common all 1:35ubuntu6 [10.8 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-common amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [833 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-json amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [16.9 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-opcache amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [76.1 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-readline amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [12.9 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-cli amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1,282 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-fpm amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1,289 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0 all 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1,292 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-mcrypt amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [14.5 kB]
Fetched 3,600 kB in 25s (143 kB/s)                                             
Selecting previously unselected package libmcrypt4.
(Reading database ... 200677 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmcrypt4_2.5.8-3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-common.
Preparing to unpack .../php-common_1%3a35ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-common (1:35ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-common_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-common (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-json.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-json_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-json (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-opcache_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-opcache (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-readline_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-readline (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-cli_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-cli (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-fpm.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-fpm_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-fpm (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0 (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-mcrypt.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-mcrypt_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-mcrypt (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.3) ...
Setting up php-common (1:35ubuntu6) ...
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-json (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-opcache (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-readline (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/readline.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-cli (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.0 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-fpm (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0 (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up php7.0-mcrypt (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini with new version
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for php7.0-fpm (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know why this happens. similarly when i tried to install **MYSQL** I got the same error. Please help me.